# iPhone Popover with AutoLayout Off

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uipopovercontroller

I am working with an old app with auto-layout turned off and I just ran into a spot where I need to display a popover on the iPhone.

The code I'm using is the routine:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {
            let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
            popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
            popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        }
    }

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
    }
```

Example result with auto-layout on:

[image]

Example result with auto-layout off:

[image]

Is there a way to show a popover using Apple's built in system without auto-layout?

Comment: Its not possible to show popover in iPhone. You need to create a UIView subclass, and display it using animation. Popover presentations are available for iPad screen only.

Comment: I know for a fact that popovers are capable on iPhone for the last couple of years now (since iOS7, i think). The code I pasted above works great but only with AutoLayout turned on.

Comment: I would recommend using https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController

Comment: Checkout this https://github.com/andreamazz/AMPopTip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the final answer is that you cannot use Apple's built in popover system on the iPhone if you turn off auto-layout.

I strongly suggest writing your own basic UIView display system that handles showing/hiding a view appropriately.

Tip: The most convenient part of the built-in popover system is that it disables the background, points to a relevant item and dismisses on outside tap, etc.

If you can live without the pointing everything else is easy to replicate because you have auto-layout turned off. You can lock the view size to "iPhone" then make the UIView background color clear and full size and drop a smaller "content" view of the appropriate size on top of it. The transparent View disables taps on items under it and you can apply a tap gesture to handle dismissal if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IOS 8 and above you can try this (Objective-C :( ).

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    UIViewController *popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The popover is still not a popover and is a full view push instead.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe is for autolayout off, because i have it in my project and popover works likes iPad